# Pagination not working in JqGrid with MVC

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jqgrid, entity-framework-6

Javascript Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetGridData")',
            datatype: 'json',
            myType: 'GET',
            colNames: ['CustomerName', 'CustomerPersonContactNo', 'Sector', 'StatusofEnquiry'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'CustomerName', index: 'CustomerName' },
                    { name: 'CustomerPersonContactNo', index: 'CustomerPersonContactNo' },
                    { name: 'Sector', index: 'Sector' },
                    { name: 'StatusofEnquiry', index: 'StatusofEnquiry' }
                ],
            jsonReader: {
                total: "total",
                page: "page",
                records: "records",
                root: "rows",
                repeatitems: false,
                id: "0"
            },
            pager: "#myPager",
            rowNum: 5,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 30],
            //sortname: 'customerName',
          //  sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "Enquiry Details",
            pagerpos: 'center'
        });

        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            SubmitEnquiryDetails();
        });

    });
```

Here is controller method

```
  public JsonResult GetGridData(jqGridViewModel objJqGridParameters)
    {
        var enquiryDetails = objEMS.EnquiryDetails;
        var count = enquiryDetails.Count();
        int pageIndex = objJqGridParameters.page;
        int pageSize = objJqGridParameters.rows;
        int startRow = (pageIndex * pageSize) + 1;
        int totalRecords = count;
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

        var JsonData = new
        {
            total =  totalPages.ToString(),
            page = pageIndex.ToString(),
            records = count.ToString(),
            rows = enquiryDetails.Select(x => new
            {
                x.CustomerName,
                x.CustomerPersonContactNo,
                x.Sector,
                x.StatusofEnquiry
            }).ToArray()
        };
        return Json(JsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My grid having 21 records, on page load I could see 5 records as per my code.
But if I navigate to the second page, records won't change they are as it is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would strictly recommend you to use `loadonce: true` scenario if you have not so many total number of items which you need to display (less as 1000 or 10000). You wrote that you have currently only 21 records. Thus `loadonce: true` should be definitively your choice. It simplify the code of the server and makes paging working more quickly from the users point of view. The code of the Action method can be

```cs
public JsonResult GetGridData() {
    return Json(objEMS.EnquiryDetails.Select(x => new
        {
            x.CustomerId,
            x.CustomerName,
            x.CustomerPersonContactNo,
            x.Sector,
            x.StatusofEnquiry
        }).ToArray(),
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

or

```cs
public JsonResult GetGridData() {
    return Json(objEMS.EnquiryDetails.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The second remark. It's strictly recommended to include native id from the database for the returned data. For example it you have `x.Id` or `x.CustomerId` property you should include it in the set of properties returned from `GetGridData()`.

The next problem. The data returned from the `url` should be sorted corresponds to `sortname` and `sortorder` parameters, which you commented now because your server code didn't processed `sidx` and `sord` parameter which send jqGrid to `url`. I'd recommend you to use the current version (4.12.1) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which supports additional option `forceClientSorting: true` which forces to sort the data *on the client side*. Thus you don't need to do this inside of `GetGridData()` action. Free jqGrid - it's fork of jqGrid, which I develop after renaming the main fork to Guriddo jqGrid JS (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)), changing the license agreement and making it commercial (see [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) the prices).

You can change the JavaScript to the following

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetGridData")',
        datatype: 'json',
        colModel: [
            { name: 'CustomerName' },
            { name: 'CustomerPersonContactNo' },
            { name: 'Sector' },
            { name: 'StatusofEnquiry' }
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            id: "CustomerId" // or id: "Id" depend on the name of ID
        },
        loadonce: true,
        forceClientSorting: true,
        pager: true,
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, "1000:All"],
        sortname: "customerName",
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Enquiry Details"
    });

    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        SubmitEnquiryDetails();
    });

});
```

The `id: "CustomerId"` property of `jsonReader` should inform jqGrid about the name of the property which contains unique values of input data. jqGrid will assign the value of `id` attribute of every row (`id` of every `<tr>` element) based on the value of the property. If the name of the property if `id`, then you can remove `jsonReader: { id: "id" }` from the options, because it's already the default value.

The option `pager: true` demonstrates another feature of free jqGrid (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/SMALL-improvements-in-the-usage-of-jqGrid)). You don't need to create an empty `<div id="myPager"></div>` and to use `pager: "#myPager"`. Instead of that you can use `pager: true` and free jqGrid will create the dive with unique id attribute for you. You can *skip* the `pager` parameter in other methods and to use `$("#myGrid").jqGrid("navGrid", { add: false, ...});` instead of `$("#myGrid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#myPager", { add: false, ...});`. Free jqGrid will just use the pager of the grid.

If you use free jqGrid then it's recommended to include CSS of [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and to add the option `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` to the grid. Some other helpful options of free jqGrid are

```
cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
autoResizing: { compact: true }
```

which allows to set the width of the columns based on the maximal width of the column content (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Auto-adjustment-of-the-width-of-column)). The user needs just make double-click on the resizer (the area in the column headers between two columns).

Good practice is the loading common CSS and JS files from CDN (free jqGrid, jQuery, jQuery UI and so on). The files are published once on CDN and there will be never changed under the URLs used. Because of that the files have long caching time and the web browser will mostly load the files *from local web browser cache* instead of loading from the server. Even loading is very quickly from CDNs. See [the documentation](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data_code). The typical `<head>` part of the page can looks like below

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Your page title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.12.0/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.12.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
```